# Set minDate in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want how to set minDate. I use this

```
$(function () {
    $("#dph-entry").datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(2017, 3, 27));
});
```

the input

```
<input type='text' class="con-input" id='dph-entry' placeholder="Entrada"/>
```

but doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `datepicker()` first. Then only `option`'s can be set.

```
$("#dph-entry").datepicker();
$("#dph-entry").datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(2017, 3, 27));
```

Better pass options while initializing

```
$("#dph-entry").datepicker({'minDate': new Date(2017, 3, 27)});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dph-entry").datepicker({
    'minDate': new Date(2017, 3, 27)
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class="con-input" id='dph-entry' placeholder="Entrada" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you use it is how you can set the min date after initialization.

> Get or set the minDate option, after initialization:
>
> **// Getter**
>
> *var minDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );*
>
> **// Setter**
>
> *$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option","minDate", new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) );*

When you are trying to set the default min date it means you are trying to init the datepicker with min date, that's why you need to add the options a bit differently, `property: value`:

> **Initialize the datepicker with the minDate option specified:**
>
> *$( ".selector" ).datepicker({   minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) });*

See the working snippet below please:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //$("#dp-entry").datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(2017, 3, 27));
    $("#dph-entry").datepicker({minDate: new Date(2017, 3, 27)});
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class="con-input" id='dph-entry' placeholder="Entrada" />
```

You can read about what I said **[here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)**.